# ModelMapper: Incorect property mapping from null objects

Tags: java, mapping, modelmapper

I'm trying to map source object which property is set to `null` to destination object of which this property is set to another object.

Expected result would be that property of destination object will be `null` after mapping. Instead of that, this property is set to an object and all of its properties are set to `null`.

Here is an example:

```
public class ModelMapperTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        User user = new User();
        user.setStatus(null);

        StatusDto statusDto = new StatusDto();
        statusDto.setId(1);
        statusDto.setName("Active");

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setStatus(statusDto);

        // user.status=null, userDto.status=StatusDto(id=1, name="Active")
        modelMapper.map(user, userDto);

        System.out.println("user = " + user);
        System.out.println("userDto = " + userDto);
    }    

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class User {
        private Status status;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class Status {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class UserDto {
        private StatusDto status;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public static class StatusDto {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
user = ModelMapperTest.User(status=null)
userDto = ModelMapperTest.UserDto(status=ModelMapperTest.StatusDto(id=null, name=null))
```

Is it possible to somehow configure model mapper to sets `UserDto.status` to null?

Comment: I  found out that there is [an issue](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/441) in `ModelMapper` library. We decided to switch to `MapStruct` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an older question and you seem to have moved on to a different library, but I had the same problem recently and came up with this solution (building on your example):

```
  Converter<?, ?> preserveNullConverter = (context) ->
     context.getSource() == null
        ? null
        : modelMapper.map(context.getSource(), context.getDestinationType());

  modelMapper.createTypeMap(User.class, UserDto.class)
     .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(preserveNullConverter).map(User::getStatus, UserDto::setStatus));
```

It's not ideal because the `.addMappings` part needs to be done for every property where the issue occurs, but at least the Converter can be reused.